# how to display data from database (MySQL)?

Tags: php, mysql

let me make clear what I wanted...I have a page where I display the data stored in database with the below code and as you can see the page displays `$row['Email']`...and in the same table I have another two rows named `Age` and `Name`..as you can see in the below code `$row['Email']` is linked to page called info.php..so when the user clicks on email he will be redirected to **info.php** and sees the Age and Name...So here is the problem I can display everyone's Age and Name on **info.php** but I only want to show single user info..Something like when you buy something online you click on an item picture or title and you will see the description....does anyone has an idea?

```
id    |  Age  |     Email            | Name
1     |  24   |  someoneAA@yahoo.com | xx1
2     |  34   |  someoneBB@yahoo.com | xx2
3     |  56   |  someoneCC@yahoo.com | xx3
4     |  19   |  someoneDD@yahoo.com | xx4

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","wht","");
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("dbase", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM User ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<td><a href='info.php'>". $row['Email']."</a></td>";
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: answer the questions before you vote down...

Comment: if this is the original code you have a typo in echo line

Comment: @SirRufo   what you mean by that? I have written every code..

Comment: What he's actually asking for is `href=info.php?id=$email"` and possibly someone to write `info.php` for him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
echo '<td><a href="info.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['Email'].'</a></td>';
```

You're passing the user id to the info.php page. This will only work if you have an Id column called `Id` in your table. Alternatively you can use `Email` instead of `Id`:

```
echo '<td><a href="info.php?email='.$row['Email'].'">'.$row['Email'].'</a></td>';
```

Now, on the info.php you can do another query as such:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE id = " . $_GET['id']);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['Age'] . ' ' . $row['Name'];
}
```

If you used `Email` instead of `Id` the first line needs to look like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE Email = " . $_GET['email']);
```

Please note this is just a guideline. You're open to sql injection and you should look into using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: thanks but it's not linking..thank you anyway than those who didn't answer and vote down

Comment: What's not linking? What's not working?

Comment: @Mark did you try this code?  You realize that you'll have to substitute an appropriate column and value for Id, right?  We don't know your database structure, so it looks like Sean just went with a guess that you have an Id column.  Alternatively, you could probably use the email if you can guarantee that they'll be unique . . .

Comment: I've updated the answer if you wanted to go with `Email` rather than `Id`.

Comment: thankyou sean I have updated my table structure...ok I'll try

Comment: I've updated my code. Take a look.

Comment: echo '<td><a href="info.php?email="'.$row['Email'].'>'.$row['Email'].'</a></td>'; is not showing the Email as link

Comment: Sorry, try my edit or `echo '<td><a href="info.php?email='.$row['Email'].'">'.$row['Email'].'</a></td>';`

Comment: thank you now that is fixed but why I'm getting this on info.php Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\send.php on line 11....is there something wrong? I just copied your code and it works on the first page but when I click on the link it gives me that error..

Comment: Try `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE Email = '" . $_GET['email'] . "'");` on info.php